# Try to call function inside controller in react component

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, webtorrent

I am trying to get use to the base code of webtorrent desktop, here you can check the code of my branch:
https://github.com/refreex/webtorrent-desktop

It uses Node.js and Electron

The problem I am facing is I create a new controller called `playlists-controller.js` and there is a function called `getAllPlaylists` that I need to consume within a React component called `playlists-list.js`

I am trying to use the same concepts that were used before but I don't understand how can i call that function from my controller inside the react's component.

There is a file called `main.js` where here are listed all the functions that the controllers have like this one:

```
  //Playlists
  'createPlaylist': (name) => controllers.playlists().createPlaylist(name),
  'addAlbumToPlaylist': (infoHash, files) => controllers.playlists().addAlbumToPlaylist(infoHash, files),
  'addSongToPlaylist': (infoHash, file) => controllers.playlists().addSongToPlaylist(infoHash, file),
  'getAllPlaylists': () => controllers.playlists().getAllPlaylists(),
```

Along the app there are a lots of calls using a dispatcher but also I think is mostly used for events but I am not sure.

So basically in the page `playlists-list.js` I need to call the function `getAllPlaylists` that is in `playlists-controller.js`

What is a good approach to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in two ways. One, passing the function as props to that component or we can export the getAllPlaylist method and use it by importing into the playlists-lists component. I hope this will help you solve your issue.

Method 1:

```
 class PlaylistController extends React.Component {

    getAllPlaylist = () => {
    alert('Do Something Here As Per Your Requirement!')
    }

    render () {
    return (
        <container>
            <PlaylistList sendFunction={this.getAllPlaylist} />
        </container>
    )
    }
}
```

class PlaylistList extends React.Component {

```
render () {
return (
    <div>
        <button onClick={this.props.sendFunction}>Click Here To Call Playlist-list Function</button>
    </div>
)
}
```

}

Method 2:

```
 class PlaylistController extends React.Component {
   export const getAllPlaylist = ()=>{
    //do something as per the requirement
   }
 }


import {getAllPlaylist} from './playlistController'

class PlaylistList extends React.Component {


    handleClick = () => {
    getAllPlaylist(); 
    }
    render () {
    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Click Here To Call Playlist-list Function</button>
        </div>
    )
    }

}
```

Comment: I think i don't need to add the controller with an import or require because any other controller is not added in there like that. 

But anyway I'll try to progress in my work with this approach meanwhile i try to understand how the people behind this make the pattern.